# JSON Parse only object

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a JSON response as

```
{ "-0.15323": "" }
```

How to Parse the `-0.15323` part only? I mean say

```
var json = '{ "-0.15323": "" }'
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Now

```
return obj;
```

should return me `-0.15323` only. Slice is not a good option. Because the data may come in variable size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a Javascript Object literal.

So you can use the Object.keys function, which is the simpler equivalent of doing a loop through all the enumerable properties with the for-in loop (like in Donal's example):

```js
var ob = {
  "-0.15323": ""
};
alert(Object.keys(ob)[0])
```

or even the Object.getOwnPropertyNames function, which FYI gives access to both enumerable and non-enumerable properties. You can access your property with:

```js
var ob = {
  "-0.15323": ""
};

alert(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ob)[0])
```

Both are Ecmascript 5, and should be supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 5):

That json is an object, so you can do something like this:

```
var obj = { "-0.15323": "" };
var key;

for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dndp2wwa/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
parseFloat(Object.keys({"-1.2345":""})[0])
```